# Talend - tOralcerow Issue

Tags: talend

Team, I'm using the below insert query to insert data into a table. But I'm getting syntax error not sure what I'm missing here,

```
 insert into employee (emp_id,dept_id,emp_nm,emp_address,insert_date) 
 values(@EMP_ID,(select max(dept_id) + 1 as dept_id from 
 department),@EMP_NM,NULL,to_char(sysdate(),”DD-MM-YYYY”))
```

Getting error as “tOraclerow - ORA-00936 missing expression” Please help on this issue.

Basically i'm getting the columns in the flow till the tOracelrow component, I need to know what is the coding or procedure on how to access the same in the query written inside the tOraclerow component.

Comment: did you try using tOracleOutput component, which will be much easier to just insert rows in a table ? (and easier to maintain)

Answer (score 0):

At the place of @EMP_ID, please use your flowname.EMP_ID

for example : row1.EMP_ID

if your column is string than put this variable in quote also like

"insert into employee (emp_id,dept_id,emp_nm,emp_address,insert_date) 
 values("+row1.EMP_ID+",(select max(dept_id) + 1 as dept_id from 
 department),'"+row1.EMP_ID+"',NULL,to_char(sysdate(),”DD-MM-YYYY”))"

Hope this helps..